# One or more of the indexers are not valid. Please add Magento cron file to crontab or launch cron.php manually

Tags: magento2, crontab

I received the above system message error on the top right hand of the screen after logging into the Admin page of Magento 2.0

When I run -> php cron.php in my magento 2.0 installation directory I get the message below

*PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: cron.php*

What could be wrong and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The `Module 'mcrypt' already loaded` message means that your PHP `*.ini` files declare the `mcrypt` PHP extension twice (maybe you have the same declaration in the both `php.ini` and `mcrypt.ini`).